# Alias template doesn't work like class template

Tags: c++, templates

I am learning about C++ templates from C++ Primer 5th edition. For example, i learnt that we could do the following:

```
template<typename T>
struct Custom 
{
    
};

template<>
struct Custom<int> 
{
  int a = 0;  
};
```

Then i learnt that C++11 also added a feature of alias templates. So i tried the same with them as shown below:

```
template<typename T>
using var = std::stack<T>;

template<>
using var<double> = double;
```

But the above shown snippet [doesn't work](https://onlinegdb.com/zk1YT2JuN). What is the problem here, why doesn't the 2nd snippet work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is that we cannot specialize an **alias templates**.

From [temp.decls 17.5.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.decls#3):

> Because an alias-declaration cannot declare a template-id, it is **not possible to partially or explicitly specialize an alias template**.